# Смена image при нажатии на элемент TreeView C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, хочу что бы было так, когда узел открыт (папка) чтобы отображалась одна картинка, когда закрыт другая, как такое делать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="FileSearch.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileSearch"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Seeker" Height="900" Width="880" Background="#FFBBD9DE" MinWidth="415" MinHeight="553"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="145*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="770*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView Name="FolderView" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="13" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </Style>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type local:FileNode}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Margin="0,1,3,1" 
                           Source="\Images\file.png" 
                           Width="16" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type local:DirectoryNode}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Margin="0,1,3,1"
                           Source="\Images\folder-closed.png" 
                           Width="16" />
                    <TextBlock 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{Binding NodeName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
    <Button Name ="Seek_Button" Content="Поиск" Grid.Column="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90" Height="40" Background="#FFA2A2A2" Click="Seek_Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.444,0.25"/>
    <Button x:Name ="Stop_Button" Content="Остановить" Grid.Column="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90" Height="40" Background="#FFA2A2A2" Click="Stop_Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox Name ="tb_filter"  Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBox Name ="tb_start_dir"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Current Directory :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Cursor="Help" FontSize="16" Height="21" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Found : " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="21" FontSize="16" Cursor="Help"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="All found : " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="21" FontSize="16" Cursor="Help"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Found, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name ="tb_found" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="150" FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AllFound, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name ="tb_all_found" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.612,0.313" Width="150" Height="29" FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentDiretory, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Height="29" FontSize="10"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.312" Width="210" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Height="21" FontSize="16"><Run Text="Spend time :"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SpendTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Height="29" FontSize="16"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот фрагмент

```xml
<Image Height="16" Margin="0,1,3,1"
       Source="\Images\folder-closed.png" 
       Width="16" />
```

Нужно доработать

```xml
<Image Height="16" Margin="0,1,3,1" Width="16">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="\Images\folder-closed.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="\Images\folder-open.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```